# Apache .htaccess query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, download

I am hosting a bunch of files on an Apache server. The files all have an extension of ".plugin" (i.e. filename.plugin ).

The files are actually zip files with the extension changed.

When downloading via Firefox the browser saves the file as "filename.plugin" which is great.

However when using IE it somehow knows this is a ZIP file and downloads it as "filename.zip".

The question is how do I force it to download with a ".plugin" extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to force it to a Mime Type, maybe the IE see that the type is a zip, try something like:

AddType application/plugin   plugin

in the httpd.conf or in the .htaccess